# Error in mysqli prepared insert statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a `table` tag. In this table there are only 2 fields `id` & `tag`. I am using mysqli prepared statement to insert in the database.

Here is the code:

```
$search='test';
// Do Prepared Query 


$result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT tag FROM tag where tag= ?");
            $result ->bind_param("s", $search);
            $result->execute();
            $result->store_result(); 
            $result->bind_result($search);

       while ($result->fetch()) {
            $tag = $tag;
       }

                if($result->num_rows != 1){ 
                    echo "Test";
                    $result1 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tag (tag) VALUES (?)");
                $result1 ->bind_param("s", $search);
                    $result1->execute();
                    $result1->store_result();

        if($result1->affected_rows == 1){
             //$res['success'] = true;
            $data[] = "Added Successfully"; 

        }


                    }

// return the result in json
echo json_encode($data);
```

For some reason it is not working. I have added the db.php file.

It is working fine until here `if($result->num_rows != 1){` because I `echo Test` there and I am getting the output.

Comment: I think you have to change `$result->store_result();` line in your code with `$result1->store_result();`.... There is `$result1` not `$result`....

Comment: echo your query and run on sql command prompt.

Comment: @KaushaMehta I did that but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried to echo the same query and execute that in mysql "SQL" section, and check what it returns?

Comment: 1.) Close your connection : $result->close(); 2.) echo $result->num_rows : What output you are getting. What error you are facing in logs ?

Comment: INSERT INTO tag (tag) VALUES 'valuesfortesting' i ran this query. getting error in phpmyadmin #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''valuesfortesting'' at line 1

Comment: @Monty Yes you are correct. I was missing $result->close(); this. It is working now. You can put that in answer. So, i can accept that.

Comment: Ok, Happy to help @404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have to close your connection properly :**

```
$result->close();
```